# eclipse turn off compilation on the fly

Tags: eclipse

I cannot find where is the option to turn off showing me compilation errors and warning "on the fly", while coding. I want it to just show me that after debug/run code try. I was looking for in project properties and view properties but cannot find it. Could you help?

Comment: try un-checking menu item: Project -> Build Automatically

Comment: nope. that's not it. doesn't work :(

Comment: This is central to the way the Eclipse Java editor works, you can't turn it off. As well as showing you errors it is required for things like autocompletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it can be turned off, I'd suggest leaving it on. You want feedback as early in the process as you can get it.

[image: Relevant Java Editor preference]

Comment: Thank you! I want to turn that off for exercising purpose. I definitely see its usefulness in "normal" coding :)